# Quadrature of the Lune

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

What is a good reference for the following result which I believe is proved by Tchebotarev.

There are exactly 5 types of Lunes that are squarable. (Hippocrates produced three and then two more were given by Euler).

Comment: @Chebolu: I added what I think are more appropriate tags (but left your original ag.algebraic-geometry tag). 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The Problem of Squarable Lunes."
M. M. Postnikov, translated from the Russian by Abe Shenitzer.
*The American Mathematical Monthly*.
Vol. 107, No. 7 (Aug.-Sep., 2000), pp. 645-651.
[JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2589121?uid=3739256&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=47698806979747).

See also the MathPages web page entitled "[The Five Squarable Lunes](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath171/kmath171.htm),"
and the Wikipedia page "[Lune of Hippocrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_of_Hippocrates)," from which this image 
of the "lunes of Alhazen" is taken:

          
[image: Lunes]

"The two blue lunes together have the same area as the green right triangle."

Comment: Note, however, that the Postnikov proof involves (p. 647) a statement whose proof "is beyond the level of this book."

Comment: @John: Interesting; I didn't notice that. The statement is that a certain single-variable polynomial of potentially high degree cannot, except in one special case, be reduced to the solution of quadratic equations.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed the theorem of Chebotarev and
Dorodnov, the original
articles are

Tschebotaröw, Nikolaj
Über quadrierbare Kreisbogenzweiecke. I. (German) Zbl 0010.00103.
Math. Z. 39, 161-175 (1934).

A. V. Dorodnov, On circular moonlets which are quadrable by compass and ruler (Russian)
Zbl 0030.10302.
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, II. Ser. 58, 965-968. (1947)

There is also a Russian translation of Chebotarev's paper in his Complete Works, vol. 1, p. 193-207. Dorodnov's paper is available only in Russian, and unfortunately cannot be found on Internet (he was a student of Chebotarev, and completed Chebotarev's proof).